# discord bot set embed message color

Tags: discord, embed, discord.py

So I made this code for sending embed messages, if you write `000000` it will make the embed black, but if you write `ff0000` for red color, it won't work, you have to write `0xff0000` for it to work, is there a way to make `ff0000` work without the `0x`? here is my code:

```
async def embed(ctx, *, content: str):
    title, description, color = content.split('|')
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=int(color, 0))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply convert the color (`ff0000`) to an int with base 16

```py
async def embed(ctx, *, content: str):
    title, description, color = content.split("|")
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, colour=int(color, 16))
```